# SQL Server stored procedure unkown number of variables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a SQL Server 2008 database with multiple tables. I am writing a stored procedure for the user to get some market values from the tables.

Eg. I have a table which has columns `Currency`, `[Market Value]`, `[Hedging]` and `[Customer ID]`.

Now the user can choose to see the Currency, Market Value and Hedging by specifying a Customer ID.

However I would like the user to be able to set multiple customer id's and see a table with aggregated values.

So for instance I would like to see the Currency, Market Value and Hedging for Customer ID 2, 3 and 7.

The `Select` statement would look something like this:

```
Select 
    [Currency], 
    sum([Market Value]), 
    sum([Hedging]) 
from 
    myDatabase
where 
    ([Customer ID] = 2 or [Customer ID] = 3 or [Customer ID] = 7)
Group by 
    [Currency], [Customer ID]
```

I could then specify a parameter and let the user decide which customer ID to use. The problem is, I do not always know which combination of customer id's that the user would like to see.

If I knew that there would always be three customer id's I could just set three parameters, but sometimes it might be only one customer id, other times it might be 5.

Is there a smooth way to come around this?

I was thinking about setting my select statement as a string and then executing it by the exec command - however my procedure is quite long with a couple of inner and left joins, temporary tables etc, so that solution might not be the best option.

Does anyone have a bright idea on how to solve this?

Comment: Use a temp table and join to it. For example you could pass an csv string to a user defined function that returns a table and then join on this table to get the results you need.

Comment: What is wrong with stored procedures??

Comment: Namphibian -> How would you do this?

Comment: @Namphibian they are on 2008 so table valued parameters would be simpler.

Comment: @MartinSmith indeed it would. Should have added that as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using SQL 2008 I would suggest a better alternative that is both strongly typed and avoids the need of creating dynamic SQL: User Defined Table Types (UDTT)

You can create a generic table type that holds integer values like so:

```
CREATE TYPE IntegerList AS TABLE 
(
    Value int NOT NULL  
)
GO
```

Then in your stored procedure you would specify a parameter of this type:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[MyProcedure]
    @customerIds IntegerList READONLY
AS
BEGIN

    -- here you can use the @customerIds variable as a (read only) table:
    SELECT Value FROM @customerIds

END
```

Comment: Yip this is a nice clean solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
where ([Customer ID] IN ({ids placeholder})
```

You can build the `SELECTreplacing` the `{ids placeholder}` with "1,3,5,... n" string

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks!
I can then create a #temp table and store the customer id's and then use a select * #temp instead of the {ids placeholder}.

Answer (score 0):

Use a parameter in your stored procedure and pass in the comma separated list as a parameter, for example:

```
Declare @customerIds nvarchar(100)
select @customerIds = '12,44,3,345'

Select [Currency], [Customer ID], sum([Market Value]), sum([Hedging]) from myDatabase
    where [Customer ID] ,in (@customerIds)
    Group by [Currency], [Customer ID]
```

Also if you want to see total aggregates, remove the [Customer ID] from your group by

```
Declare @customerIds nvarchar(100)
select @customerIds = '12,44,3,345'

Select [Currency], sum([Market Value]), sum([Hedging]) from myDatabase
    where [Customer ID] ,in (@customerIds)
    Group by [Currency]
```

Comment: This solution gives the error message: "Error converting data type nvarchar to bigint." :/